# VB Installation problems with crystl32.dll and CRPE32.dll

Tags: dll, vb6, visual-studio-6

I installed VB6 onto my machine.

1. Whenever I open VB6 editor, it is asking for a "Dell Resource" CD
2. When I open VB6 Project. It gives me errors saying

> SVGControl.dll could not be loaded

Googling tells that Adobe SVG viewer needs to be present. But installing that does not solve the problem. This dll is present in System32, but when I register, it throws a `LoadError`.

3. Another error saying `crystl32.dll` could not be found. I installed Crystl32.exe from VB installer. But that was not successful. It shows error like `Ordinal 1132 could not be located in DLL CRPE32.dll`. Also, upon copying this dll to system32 and registering, it throws `LoadError`.

Any ideas on how to solve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?  If Vista/Win7 uninstall and rerun the install "As Administrator"

Possible fix for the [crystl32 error](http://www.planet-source-code.com/URLSEO/vb/Discussion/AskAProShowPost!asp/lngTopicId!34263/TopicCategory!OCX+_And_+3rd+party+controls/Flag!2/lngWId!1/blnURLSEO!true/Posting.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I installed VB6 on a machine without .NET. The Crystl32.exe installation was successful. Now the error 1 is solved.

However when i open a VB 6 project I get the following errors:
1. SVGControl cannot be loaded
2. Crst32.ocx cannot be loaded